# Dataimport in Solr 5.1.0 is not indexing few fields which are to be fetched through makepair function

Tags: java, solr

Schema.xml has all fields mentioned to be indexed. it was working all this time and i am facing this issue all of a sudden. What is wrong. Please advise.

**Error :**

```
 Line 2458: WARN  - 2016-10-10 19:53:56.757; [   iccCore] 
 org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.EntityProcessorWrapper; transformer
 threw error    Line 2459:
 org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Error
 invoking script for entity icMetadataProcessed Processing Document #
 2594   Line 2472: Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError:
 null has no such function "split" in <eval> at line number 8   Line
 2478: Caused by: <eval>:8 TypeError: null has no such function "split"
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a Javascript error in your custom script. Possibly about the script expecting a string (to split) and getting null. I would fix the javascript to ignore that field or add debug to see which record is causing that problem, must likely by missing a value.